# Multivalued Attribute

Tags: sql, database

Assume here we have a column to describe the description of a product.

I think I have to use multivalue to fill in the table.

Is that kind of mistake to violate the principle of 1NF?

I am beginner to database design, recently I feel really confused about it.

Comment: Are you saying each product has multiple descriptions?

Comment: No, Single description with multiple words. Things like "iPhone" - “Revolutionary Apple Product”

Comment: `"iPhone" - "Revolutionary Apple Product"` is not a multivalued attribute. It's just an attribute with several words. A multivalued attribute would e.g. "available_colors" with the (single) value `"white,black"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1NF specifically disallows multi values attributes, so yes, having multiple distinct values in a field would violate it.

However, a **single** field that contains many words, so long as they are a **single** conceptual value (such as a description composed of many words), is fine.

In general it is a bad idea - it makes querying harder (joining is very difficult), you will not benefit from indexing and these are just the most obvious issues.

Answer (score 0):

Spaces do not always define seperate values.

Your example shows a sentance, which is one value.

However, if these were keywords, the order of which was irrelevent, then you could say it violates 1NF.

Comment: Is that means I can combine the "FirstName" and "LastName" to be a single table "Name" without violating 1NF?

Comment: Technically yes, both names together form one full name. They are often split because they are used independently e.g. <Title> <LastName> or just <FirstName> on it's own. If this is the case, then treating them as one value is incorrect. If they will always be used together, then you can argue they are a single atomic unit and have just a <Name> column.